# mongodb: how to query a record that doesn't have a column

Tags: mongodb

I want to find out a record that doesn't have the "name" column, how to do it in mongo console?

Thanks.
Bin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be

```
 db.things.find( { name : { $exists : false } } ); // return if name is missing
```